# lxml xpass can't find a tag below first one in xml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have an xml doc that looks something like this

```
<MyXmlRoot>
<App xmlns='urn:SomethingSomething1'>
    ...
</App>
<User xmlns='urn:SomethingSomething2'>
    ...
</User>
<Doc xmlns='urn:SomethingSomething3'>
    <level2>
        <level3>
            <level4>
                <level5>
                    <level6>
                        <level7>
                            <level8>
                                <level9>
                                    <level10>Content at the deepest level</level10>
                                </level9>
                            </level8>
                        </level7>
                    </level6>
                </level5>
            </level4>
        </level3>
    </level2>
</Doc>
```

I use lxml to read it and parse it like this

```
tree = etree.parse("textxml.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
```

if I do pretty print from root it will show the entire xml. which is good but when I try to read specific tags values like so

```
content = root.xpath('//level10/text()')
```

xpath can't find any tag below the root and returns empty list
I suspect it's because of the namespaces but can't find a solution to make xpath read values
any advice ?

Comment: Please edit your question, and provide a well-formed input XML.

Comment: @MichaelKay closing as duplicated after the question got answered. Typical SO mod. Come back to this question 5 years after to modify it also, just to live up to the memes

Comment: Actually, I don't think it's a bad thing if a question is answered and then closed as a duplicate. The answer helps the person who raised the question, the closing as a duplicate helps people who come along later. I'm generally disinclined to close questions as duplicates, but there are thousands of questions where the answer is "XPath default namespace" and they don't add to the value of the site.

Comment: @MichaelKay in many cases closed as a duplicate is being overused. look at the link you added - 15 years old question on c#, while here we are talking about python in 2024. would that link contain useful information? mb yes mb no, many things might change since that question was posted, mb there are new methods to deal with this problem - a beginner might not know it and it will result in even more confusion. Also I believe when you are a beginner the process of asking questions is a part of learning and current SO policy actively punishes it leading negative reputation of the entire site

Comment: There's a balance between meeting the immediate needs of the questioner and building up a long-term repository of questions and answers. I think that answering a question and then closing as a duplicate is one useful way to achieve that balance. I agree it's very difficult to decide on "duplicate" closures, and the XPath default namespace problem is a classic example: people make the same underlying mistake in many different ways and the mistake results in a wide variety of symptoms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add xmlns `{urn:SomethingSomething3}` to the tag you want to search:

```py
from lxml import etree

xml_data = """
<MyXmlRoot>
    <App xmlns='urn:SomethingSomething1'>
    </App>
    <User xmlns='urn:SomethingSomething2'>
    </User>
    <Doc xmlns='urn:SomethingSomething3'>
        <level2>
            <level3>
                <level4>
                    <level5>
                        <level6>
                            <level7>
                                <level8>
                                    <level9>
                                        <level10>Content at the deepest level</level10>
                                    </level9>
                                </level8>
                            </level7>
                        </level6>
                    </level5>
                </level4>
            </level3>
        </level2>
    </Doc>
</MyXmlRoot>
"""

root = etree.fromstring(xml_data)

level10_text = root.find(".//{urn:SomethingSomething3}level10").text
print("Text from <level10> tag:", level10_text)
```

Prints:

```
Text from <level10> tag: Content at the deepest level
```

---

OR: Use `etree.ETXPath`:

```py
to_search = etree.ETXPath("//{urn:SomethingSomething3}level10/text()")
level10_text = to_search(root)
print("Text from <level10> tag:", level10_text)
```

Prints:

```
Text from <level10> tag: ['Content at the deepest level']
```

Comment: what's going be the main difference aside of find returns string while ETXPath search gets a list ?

Comment: @VladimirZaguzin With `ETXPath` you can use rich selectors, such as `text()` here - but it returns all matches (here a list with one string, because you have only one `<level10>` tag) - [doc](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.ETXPath-class.html)

Comment: lxml description [ETXPath](https://lxml.de/1.3/xpathxslt.html#etxpath)